# Sort in ascen/desc div by id using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html

"I want to sort the divs in ascending/descending order
and where div id is dynamic like

```
 "<div id="main">
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-India"></div>
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_122893_Y_AA_American-Airlines"></div>
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_162891_Y_S2_Air-Sahara"></div>
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_152894_Y_9W_jJet-Airways"></div>
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_172895_Y_AI_Air-India"></div>
  <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_192898_Y_RA_Nepal-Airlines"></div>
</div>"
```

div should be sort by given parameter like it can be 'Y' or it can be 'Air-India'
these values are given in div id seperated by underscore like in above div id="FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-India"

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: What is providing the dynamic nature of the ids? Most likely you'll find it is simpler to sort at that point rather than in the JavaScript.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a valid question.

Comment: this is a new user with 1 reputation, I don't think downvotes will help here

Comment: Actually i am new user, i search many options but didn't find the solution so i post it here,                                     there is format in Div id "FlightResult_" is prefix in every div "2" is trip-type, that 6 digit number i.e "142897" is price , 'Y' is status refundable or non-refundable , AI is airlinescode and Air-India is full name of that airlines. so if i click in price button it should sort (Ascending and descending both) by price given in div id likewise for other every options too      please help me if any solutions, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpliest solution would be to use the jQuery library and a sort plugin.
The sort plugin can be found here:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

You can ask me question if something is wrong with the following code or if you don't understand some parts.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jqplugin/sort.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                // Get the option "opt" which is in the attribute "rel" of the button clicked:
                // 1 - Sort by trip type
                // 2 - Sort by price
                // 3 - Sort by refundable status
                // 4 - Sort by airline code
                // 5 - Sort by airline full name
                var opt = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));

                var my_button = $(this);

                $('#main .fr').sort(function(a, b) {
                    // The inputs "a" and "b" are 2 div lines of class "fr". 
                    // We will compare these for sorting

                    // Get the information of "a" and "b", stored in their ID attribute
                    var infoA = $(a).attr("id").split("_");
                    var infoB = $(b).attr("id").split("_");
                    var nameA = null;
                    var nameB = null;

                    nameA = infoA[opt];
                    nameB = infoB[opt];

                    var output = null;

                    if($(my_button).hasClass("desc"))
                        return nameB.toUpperCase() > nameA.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1;
                    else
                        return nameA.toUpperCase() > nameB.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1;
                });

                if($(this).hasClass("desc"))
                    $(my_button).removeClass("desc")
                else
                    $(this).addClass("desc")
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-India">1 - FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-India</div>
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_122893_Y_AA_American-Airlines">2 - FlightResult_1_122893_Y_AA_American-Airlines</div>
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_162891_N_S2_Air-Sahara">3 - FlightResult_2_162891_N_S2_Air-Sahara</div>
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_152894_Y_9W_jJet-Airways">4 - FlightResult_1_152894_Y_9W_jJet-Airways</div>
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_2_172895_N_AI_Air-India">5 - FlightResult_2_172895_N_AI_Air-India</div>
          <div class="fr" id="FlightResult_1_192898_Y_RA_Nepal-Airlines">6 - FlightResult_1_192898_Y_RA_Nepal-Airlines</div>
            </div>
            <button id="sort_trip_type" rel="1">Sort By Trip Type</button>
            <button id="sort_price" rel="2">Sort By Price</button>
            <button id="sort_refund_status" rel="3">Sort By Refundable Status</button>
            <button id="sort_air_code" rel="4">Sort By Airlines Code</button>
        <button id="sort_air_name" rel="5">Sort By Airlines Full Name</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please post me the example, because without example its hard for me to implement.

Comment: Hey friend, sorry for my late reply. I modified my previous comment. Try the following code. Hope it helps. You can ask question if needed :)

Comment: Thank you so much friend, it really worked for my project. Thank you so much, u r a genius. I will keep following you.

Comment: Your welcome friend I'm happy to help :). Don't forget to validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

//First load the div id's into an array and then sort the array according to the order you want e.g

```
var div_array = ["FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-   India","FlightResult_1_122893_Y_AA_American-Airlines","FlightResult_2_162891_Y_S2_Air-Sahara","FlightResult_1_152894_Y_9W_jJet-Airways"];
```

//then sort the array

```
div_array.sort();
```

//then add to the main div

```
for(var i=o; i< div_array.length ; i++)
{
   $("#main").append($("<div class='fr' id='"+ div_array[i] +"'> </div>"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you S.McGrady for your reply , your logic seems good , could you please help me again how do i sort the array var div_array = ["FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air-   India","FlightResult_1_122893_Y_AA_American-Airlines","FlightResult_2_162891_Y_S2_Air-Sahara","FlightResult_1_152894_Y_9W_jJet-Airways"]; by price which is in div id separated by underscore  Thank you in advance .

Comment: use div_array.sort(function(a,b){return b-a}); that's if you want from highest price to lowest. Just reverse a and b if you want it vice versa.

Comment: how does it work? how does it seperate price from "FlightResult_2_142897_Y_AI_Air- India" this didn't solved my problem. could you please post the complete code.